# convert the data of a text file into variable

Tags: c, file

I know my question has been already asked by other people, but being a beginner in C,

I frankly do not comprehend the answers to those questions.

I am currently using Windows and my code is C (I am using VS2012)

This is the content of my text file:

```
Bulwark Fury // Assign this string into player.name
Red Steel // Assign this string into player.title
230 // Assign this string into player.typenclass
21  // Assign this string into player.startstr
2.9  // Assign this string into player.incstr
16  // Assign this string into player.startdex
1.6 // Assign this string into player.incdex
16  // Assign this string into player.startintel
1.7 // Assign this string into player.incintel
44  // Assign this string into player.basemindmg
60  // Assign this string into player.basemaxdmg
1.7 // Assign this string into player.baseattacktime
1.24 // Assign this string into player.basearmor
```

Code:

```
typedef struct nodebase
{
    char name[20],title[20],type[15],Class[15];
    int typenclass;
    int startstr;
    double incstr;
    int startdex;
    double incdex;
    int startintel;
    double incintel;
    int basemindmg,basemaxdmg;
    double baseattacktime;
    double basearmor;
    struct nodebase *next;
    struct nodebase *curr;
    struct nodebase *prev;
}herostat;

static void stat_file(const char *file_name, herostat player)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(file_name, "r");// open the specified file
    if (f != NULL)
    {
        int c;
        while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF)// read character from file until EOF
        {
            fscanf(f,"%s\n%s\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n",
                    &player.name, &player.title, &player.typenclass,
                    &player.startstr, &player.incstr, &player.startdex,
                    &player.incdex, &player.startintel, &player.incintel,
                    &player.basemindmg, &player.basemaxdmg,
                    &player.baseattacktime, &player.basearmor);
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

I tried running this and print the variables just to make sure if fscanf worked well,

but when what were printed were some random numbers...

Please Help!

Comment: I frankly do not comprehend the answers to those questions. That just shows you haven't done research.

Comment: by the way, the code is a text file?

Comment: How do you expect to read `2.9` into an `int` (`incstr`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's code has a number of issues

- Biggest issue is trying to read text like "1.24" into an `int`.  No only does this not work, the subsequent use of the format in `fscanf()` does not readily consume the `.`.  Solution: scan floating-point point numbers into floating-point variables.

.

```
// int baseattacktime;
double baseattacktime;
// "%d"
"%lf"
```

.

1. `c = fgetc(f)` is curious and not needed.
2. The use of `'\n'` does not scan in only a line-feed, but *any* white space.  `%d` skips over leading white space anyways, so `"%d"` is the same as `" %d"`.
3. As OP is reading a text file, recommend `fopen(file_name, "rt")`.   `t` added.
4. Format statement may scan in too many characters.  Use `%19s` rather than `%s`.
5. OP is not checking `fscanf()` result.
6. OP wants to scan in names with spaces.  Avoid `%s` which does not scan spaces.  Use `%[^\n]`.
7. Breaking up the ponderous `fscanf()` would be useful.
8. If multiple players need to be read, space must be allocated for them.

---

Example code

```
typedef struct nodebase {
    char name[20],title[20],type[15],Class[15];
    int typenclass;
    int startstr;
    doubel incstr;
    int startdex
    double incdex;
    int startintel;
    double incintel;
    double basemindmg,basemaxdmg;  // Assume these 4 need to be FP
    double baseattacktime;
    double basearmor;
    struct nodebase *next;
    struct nodebase *curr;
    struct nodebase *prev;
}herostat;


if (f != NULL) {
  while (13 == fscanf(f," %19[^\n]  %19[^\n]%d" "%d%lf%d" "%lf%d%lf" "%lf%lf%lf%lf",
      &player.name, &player.title, &player.typenclass,
      &player.startstr, &player.incstr, &player.startdex,
      &player.incdex, &player.startintel, &player.incintel,
      &player.basemindmg, &player.basemaxdmg,
      &player.baseattacktime, &player.basearmor);
    // do something with player
    }
  fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: May I ask what does while (13 ==fscanf) does?

Comment: @Sung Min Kim  `fscanf()` returns the number of fields successfully scanned.  As you want 13 variables filled, should the scanning process not equal 13, something went wrong.

Comment: Then can I use while (13 == fscanf) to scan the content of a file whose numbers of contents I do know of?

Comment: For example, there is a text file content that I need my program to read. Let's say the content is about client's data. Each client has 13 lines of data such as Age:, Sex:, Name:, Address:, etc. So by counting the file content by 13, I will be able to know how many clients there are in the file. Will It work that way? I know the code should tell the program to read the file until it reaches EOF

Comment: @Sung Min Kim  Yes.  Recommend that you create a linked list to chain each new record with the old one so you may make _one_ pass through the file and cope with a file of a few hundred bytes to billions of bytes.

Comment: So can a linked list store the specific numbers of data in a file into their respective variables and at the same time, count how many "set" of data are there within the file?

Comment: @Sung Min Kim Yes.  As the linked list grows, one can keep a count of the link list's length or simple determine the linked list's length after reading everything.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, chux! I'd better start learning the linked-list. It is difficult for me to understand, although I think I understood it... Can you suggest me any sites to study on this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list